# cordova screen orientation not resizing window to 100% on ios - ionic app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a specific requirement to maximize a graph on click of a button, so I am trying to lock the orientation to landscape and let the window automatically resize, but when I do it through

```
$cordovaScreenOrientation.lockOrientation('landscape');
```

the windown failed to resize to 100%, but it works fine in android though.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2mywnwVFRuKTjhlZDJSV2ZlSlE

This is where it is supposed to attain 100%

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2mywnwVFRuKT2I2eDZkSVZ1VHM

Answer (score 0):

phew...everything gotta go inside

```
 ionic.Platform.ready( function() { ... })
```

learnt that hard way.